# Div overflowing off the right side of the screen - iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have a div that pops up with javascript that works great now on all browsers ... except on iphones.  On the iphone it doesn't wrap the words, but extends the width of the div off the right side of the screen and I can't view the details.

I have tested on my android phone and all is good.  I created a jsfiddle, but I don't think I can emulate different devices on there:  http://jsfiddle.net/rasweat/xwx6o8ap/

Here is my CSS code: (which I thought handled safari, but I guess not)

```
.PopupPanel
{
    border: solid 2px black;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index: 100000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    overflow: auto;

    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);   

    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

Comment: Clearly `50px,100px` which Safari reads is different than the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pangloss pointed out, the different part is **`-webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px);`** declaration, since all versions of Safari (including Safari 8) does not natively support `transform` property, means Safari only renders `-webkit-transform`.

```
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */

/*Changed the code below this*/
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari */
/*Changed the code above this*/

transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Rest of the world */
```

Latest: Firefox, Chrome and Opera (Blink based) are not affected.

Learn more here - http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Orlando, Thank you so much!  You are awesome for pointing this out.  I think sometimes changing code 100 times makes you miss the simplest of things.

Comment: What you suggested was not entirely correct, I just updated it.

Comment: All for the sake of correctness I guess, thanks @Pangloss :)